# Youtube API can't find my functions

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, ecmascript-6

I am developing a web app using Youtube's iframe API and writing code in ECMA6 style, but am running into some issues. I followed the youtube API documentation and created an iframe player object with an 'OnReady' event that calls my initializing function.

However, for some unexplainable reason, if I try to call another function from within the initializing function, I get an error saying the function I called does not exist, when it clearly does. Obviously I'm misunderstanding the thread of execution here because the youtube player is unable to find functions that are seemingly already there.

Here is the code I have for one of my controllers. The youtube player is created in the controller's constructor and it is supposed to call initTimes. This initializing function should then call updateTimes which manages the times for the player, but it keeps telling me "updateTimes is not a function" even though I have it defined above(it just prints to the console for now). Does anyone have an explanation for what I am missing?

```
  export default class ChatCtrl extends Controller {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.currentVideoId = this.$stateParams.videoId;
    this.chatId = this.$stateParams.chatId;
    this.videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.currentVideoId + "?enablejsapi=1";

    this.isIOS = Ionic.Platform.isWebView() && Ionic.Platform.isIOS();
    this.isCordova = Meteor.isCordova;

    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
      events: {
        'onReady': this.initTimes,
      }
    });
  }

  updateTimes() {
    console.log("timing");
  }

  initTimes() {
    // Update current time text display.
    this.updateTimes();
  }


}
```

Comment: `this.initTimes` should be `this.initTimes.bind(this)`

Comment: Wow, I knew there was a problem with scoping but since I'm new to ecma6 I didn't know you could bind scope like that. Thanks a ton, if you make your comment an answer I can set it as the solution.